# Alter the Math functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to "alter" the sin cos and tan function from Math object so it can accept recognize if it is a degree "d" or radians. I have an idea on how to do it but I do not know to do it without changing my main function

```js
(function() {
   var angle;
         
   while (angle = parseFloat(readline())) {
      print(Math.sin(angle, "d").toPrecision(5));  // degrees
      print(Math.sin(angle).toPrecision(5));       // radians
      print(Math.cos(angle, "d").toPrecision(5));
      print(Math.cos(angle).toPrecision(5));
      print(Math.tan(angle, "d").toPrecision(5));
      print(Math.tan(angle).toPrecision(5));
   }
})();
```

How do alter does function so they can accept the "d" argument I tried use Object.create and another things like JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Math)); but it doesn't work I need to know how to deep copy Math

Comment: Why don't you define a custom function to differentiate between degrees/radian input and make it call the sin/cos/tan functions from within it?

Comment: Like function toRad() { ...//I call my math functions} but how that helps in main I can't change the main function

Comment: I meant to say, define a `function YourOwnSinFunc(angle, isRadian) { if (isRadian) { Math.sin(angle); }else { //do computing Math.sin(angleinradians); }` and call it from your code instead of Math.sin directly!

Comment: If you can't change the calling code, how will it ever use this new feature?

Comment: Artificial restrictions like "can't change the main function", especially when you _need_ to change it to use the feature (as @Ingo points out) reeks of classwork. In which case you probably should be working it out yourself. It's not as if we don't already _have_ enough lazy coders in the industry :-)

Comment: It is just practice I got stuck in this problem

Comment: @IngoBürk I am not sure if the OP's code is non-editable, because in its current state it wouldn't even work (with unsupported arguments for the Math functions).

Answer (score 1):

You can override `Math` (in a closure) with an object which inherits from `Math`:

```
(function(globalMath) {

    // Overriding Math:
    var Math = Object.create(globalMath);

    // Enhancing trigonometric methods:
    var trig = ['sin', 'cos', 'tan'];
    for(var i=0; i<3; ++i)
        Math[trig[i]] = (function(trigFunc){
            return function(angle, d) {
                if(d==="d") angle *= Math.PI / 180;
                return trigFunc(angle);
            };
        })(globalMath[trig[i]]);

    // Now you can use the enhanced methods:
    Math.sin(Math.PI/6); // 0.5
    Math.sin(30, 'd');   // 0.5

    // You can also use original methods:
    globalMath.sin(Math.PI/6);      // 0.5
    globalMath.sin(Math.PI/6, 'd'); // 0.5 ('d' is ignored)

    // Math is a shortcut of globalMath for other methods:
    Math.max(1,2); // 2

})(Math);
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything's an Object in JavaScript, so you can re-write the native `Math` functions. But this is not recommended, as other commentators have said.

It's simpler to create your own function that converts to degrees internally, like this:

```
function sinDegrees(angle) {
    return Math.sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180));
}
```

It could even be part of the `Math` object, if you want:

```
Math.sinDegrees = sinDegrees;
```

---

If you still want to modify the `Math.sin` function like that, then you can do this:

```
Math._sin = Math.sin; // save a ref. to the old sin
Math.sin = function sin(angle, type) {
    if (type == 'd')
        return Math._sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180));
    else
        return Math._sin(angle);
}
```

Comment: I was going to talk about redefining the function. But then it possibly could break other code, which is making use of the inbuilt method. So, the OP should take care not to break the existing functionality. Note: Your sample would still allow calls to original sin to be successful, but I am just saying that anyone who is following this approach should take care of it too!

Comment: Ok so _sin is pointing to Math.sin but then I Math.sin is pointing to a new function. I tried to do this but with Math.sin = function(); and it felt why is that? It was calling recursively.

Comment: @user2822413: Worked correctly using the code as I posted it, here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2r1ndbn4/).

Comment: @user2822413: Because the parentheses at the end of `math.sin` are calling the function instead of just taking the function object as-is.

Comment: I am trying var _sin = Math.sin;  and then calling Math.sin = function(degree, angle) {... this._sin..} why does not work?

Comment: @user2822413: In that function `this` refers to `Math`, not `window` (that's just how functions within objects work). Just remove the `this.` part.

Answer (score 0):

The better solution here is to have a toRad function.  It looks very similar to your target code without breaking basic good practices (don't modify objects you didn't create).

```
function toRad(angle){
    return angle * (Math.PI / 180);
}

print(Math.sin(toRad(angle)).toPrecision(5));  // degrees
print(Math.sin(angle).toPrecision(5));       // radians
print(Math.cos(toRad(angle)).toPrecision(5));
print(Math.cos(angle).toPrecision(5));
print(Math.tan(toRad(angle)).toPrecision(5));
print(Math.tan(angle).toPrecision(5));
```

This also saves you from defining custom versions of each function.